# AddUriPathExtensionMapping part of XmlFormatters?

Tags: xml, razor, twilio

I am trying to follow some example code that uses the following ...

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "application/xml");
```

However, I am finding that `.AddUriPathExtensionMapping` does not exist withing within the `HttpConfiguration.Formatters.XmlFormatter` namespace.

I am pretty sure the sample code is correct. Could the location of `.AddUriPathExtensionMapping` changed? If so, could someone show how it might be used currently?

The example I am trying to follow is listed here ..

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/11/building-twilio-apps-using-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api.html

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.mediatypeformatterextensions.adduripathextensionmapping(v=vs.108).aspx) referenced in the post, it seems that the namespace is `System.Net.Http.Formatting` and the `MediaTypeFormatter` class.

If you are interested in additional .NET MVC examples, I would suggest having a look at [tutorials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials).

Please let me know if this helps at all.